# Detecting OS based on files unique to the operating system

Tags: linux, operating-system

I'm looking for a way to identify the operating system based on the files. My primary goal is to identify the files that will distinguish a Macintosh system from other Unix Based systems. I have already removed Windows from the list(that contains all hard disk partitions) by checking the existence of system32 folder. Also, I want to make sure that this distinguishing file has been available since the start of Macintosh OS (at least since Snow Leopard). I tried detecting Applications folder and it seems to work fine but I have a small fear that any other flavor of Linux might happen to have the Applications folder which is why I'm posting this query here. Do let me know the various options I have (whether file or  folder) to detect the OS. Thanks in advance

Comment: MacOSX and other Unixes all have [uname(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/uname.2.html) from Posix... And Linux don't have any *Applications* directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not the uname command?

```
calvin@desktop $ uname 
Linux

calvin@hayden-07 $ uname
Darwin
```

As for file based. Linux and some BSDs have /proc file systems, whereas Mac OSX does not. if you see a /proc folder you've got a good bet it's not Mac

follow-up to the /proc tip. This might help

```
calvin@barnabas:~$ cat /proc/version
Linux version 3.2.0-4-amd64 (debian-kernel@lists.debian.org) (gcc version 4.6.3     (Debian 4.6.3-14) ) #1 SMP Debian 3.2.51-1
```

Comment: I have access to the files and cannot run the processes. But that /proc tip is useful. Thanks

Comment: Also try `/etc/lsb-release` and `/etc/issue`

Comment: Yes that's perfect for isolating the linux flavor from the various possibilities! Thanks